# Message "MM_WOM_DONE" is not called

Tags: c, windows, winapi, winmm

I have a problem: i don't recieve "MM_WOM_DONE" once audio block finishes playing.

Code related to sound:

```
void initSound(HWND hwnd) {
    HWAVEOUT hWaveOut;
    WAVEFORMATEX wfx;

    wfx.nSamplesPerSec = 44100; /* sample rate */
    wfx.wBitsPerSample = 8; /* sample size */
    wfx.nChannels = 1; /* channels*/

    wfx.cbSize = 0;
    wfx.wFormatTag = WAVE_FORMAT_PCM;
    wfx.nBlockAlign = (wfx.wBitsPerSample >> 3) * wfx.nChannels;
    wfx.nAvgBytesPerSec = wfx.nBlockAlign * wfx.nSamplesPerSec;

    if(waveOutOpen(&hWaveOut, WAVE_MAPPER, &wfx, (DWORD)hwnd, 0, CALLBACK_WINDOW) != MMSYSERR_NOERROR) {
        printf("Wave out can't be opened!\n");
        ExitProcess(1);
    } else {
        printf("Wave out is now open!\n");
    }

    /* Building a block */
    DWORD size = 8192;
    int frequency = 523; // C note
    int volume = 20;
    float sinMul = 3.1415 * frequency / (wfx.nSamplesPerSec);
    unsigned char blockArray[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        blockArray[i] = 128 + (signed char)(sin(i * sinMul) * volume);
    }

    WAVEHDR header;
    ZeroMemory(&header, sizeof(WAVEHDR));
    header.dwBufferLength = size;
    header.lpData = (LPSTR)&blockArray;
    printf("Block was created!\n");

    /* Prepearing header */
    printf("Prepearing header for wave out...\n");
    waveOutPrepareHeader(hWaveOut, &header, sizeof(WAVEHDR));

    /* Playing a block */
    printf("Writing sound to wave out...\n");
    waveOutWrite(hWaveOut, &header, sizeof(WAVEHDR));
    printf("Waiting sound for finishing playing...\n");
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch(msg) {
        case WM_CREATE:
            initSound(hwnd);
        break;
        case MM_WOM_DONE:
            printf("Sine wave stopped playing!");
            waveOutUnprepareHeader((HWAVEOUT)wParam, (LPWAVEHDR)lParam, sizeof(WAVEHDR));
            waveOutClose((HWAVEOUT)wParam);
        break;
    }
}
```

Console output:

```
Wave out is now open!
Block was created!
Prepearing header for wave out...
Writing sound to wave out...
Waiting sound for finishing playing...
```

The sine wave plays well and correct, but once it finishes playing, some short white noise starts playing for short amount of time (nearly 100-200 ms). Also "Sine wave stopped playing!" message never shows up in the console, which means WndProc function is never called with "MM_WOM_DONE" message. If i handle everything in "initSound" function, sine wave plays with no white noise in the end even when delay between writing and closing waveOut is much bigger (more than one second).

Comment: are you calling GetMessage()/PeekMessage() in your main()? Just asking because you didn't post it.

Comment: Yup. All other events like WM_PAINT and WM_KEYDOWN are working good, multiple times and until i close the window. MM_WOM_DONE is the only one i have problems with.

Comment: @Shuriken255 do you receive `MM_WOM_OPEN`? Also, you are not checking for errors on `waveOutPrepareHeader()` and `waveOutWrite()`. Also, try allocating the `WAVEHDR` dynamically on the heap instead of on the stack, since it needs to be kept alive in memory until you unprepare it, which you are doing asynchronously.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Moving wave header and block data to heap fixed the problem. Now no noise appears and i recieve MM_WOM_OPEN message through WndProc function. You can now post answer and i will mark it as correct one. Thank you very much for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credits for solving this problem to Remy Lebeau. The mistake i did is storing wave header and wave out header in stack rather than in heap. This resulted in noise appearence because data was overriden and sound card started reading invalid data. Wave out header was also probably lost or/and overwritten so i could not get proper call of MM_WOM_DONE message. All this was solved simply for declaring variables outside function. Just like this:

```
HWAVEOUT hWaveOut;
WAVEFORMATEX wfx;
DWORD size = 8192;
WAVEHDR header;

void initSound(HWND hwnd) {
    /* Body of function */
}
```

So in case if you have this problem, be sure your variables related to waveout live long enough.

Comment: Great! You can mark your own answer so that  members of the community can benefit from this thread.

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT oops, sorry, forgot to do that. Actually, i have to wait for 2 days before i can do that. Also, wanted to let Remy Lebeau to write answer and earn one more "accepted answer" badge because he is the one who solved this problem.

Comment: Don't forget about the buffer array!